# How can I prove or disprove if log(f(n)) ∈ O(log(g(n)) then f(n) ∈ O(g(n))?

Tags: analysis

How can I prove or disprove this statement? If it's false, do I use a counter-example? This is using BIG O.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to MathStackExchange! Please see here, "https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask ", to learn how to ask a good question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try $f(n) = n^2$ and $g(n) = n$.

Are there constants $M,N$ satisfying $\log f(n) \le M \log g(n)$ and $f(n) \le N g(n)$?

Comment: Would M = 2 and N = n not work?